# JQuery Randomly Stops Working ( .size() )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, size

So I made a form and I am trying to validate it with javascript before it is processed. Every other field works perfectly fine. This is how the form looks.

```
<form name="game_sub" action="add_game.php" onsubmit="return gameVal()" method="post">
        <table>

            <tr><td><input type="text" name="name" class="game_name" placeholder="NAME" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <select name="keyword" >
                <option value="action">Action</option>
                <option value="platform">Platform</option>
                <option value="sport">Sport</option>
                <option value="shooter">Shooter</option>
            </select>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td><label>Game: </label><input type="file" name="game_file" id="g_file"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><label>Thumbnail: </label><input type="file" name="game_thumb" id="t_file"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><textarea name="desc" placeholder="DESCRIPTION"></textarea></td></tr>
        </table>
        <a href="index.php"><button type="button" id="add_btn_lft" class="add_btn">CANCEL</button></a>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="add_btn_rgt" class="add_btn"/>
```

Then I add the javascript. The javascript has 1 little line of jQuery within it by which I already added the google jquery source script to the top of the page. It worked for like 1 hour perfectly, I left, and came back and it's broken. I checked what was wrong with it by turning some of my lines into comments to see if its absence would make it work again. I did and when I removed the variable:

```
var TSize = document.forms.game_sub.game_thumb.form[0].size;
```

The whole script came back to life. I was using the .size from jQuery to acquire the size of the file in bites and it was working for a while but I have no idea what happened ... It just randomly decided not to work. Is there a problem with javascript executing jQuery within it? I've done it before and had no problem but this is odd.

This is how my .js file looks:

```
function gameVal() {

  var GName = document.forms.game_sub.name.value;
  var GCat = document.forms.game_sub.keyword.value;
  var GFile = document.forms.game_sub.game_file.value;
  var GThumb = document.forms.game_sub.game_thumb.value;
  var Tarea = document.forms.game_sub.desc.value;
  var BErr = document.getElementById("add_game_err");
  var GFile2 = GFile.split(".");
  var GThumb2 = GThumb.split(".");
  var imgExt = ["jpg", "jiff", "jpeg", "gif", "tiff"];
  var gameExt = ["swf", "unity3d"];

  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

  if (GFile == "" || GThumb == "" || GName == "" || GName == null || GCat == "Category" || Tarea == "") {
    BErr.style.display = "block";
    BErr.innerHTML = "Please fill in all the fields.";
    return false;
  }
  else if (GFile2.length > 2) {
    BErr.style.display = "block";
    BErr.innerHTML = "Please make sure the game file name has no periods(.) within it.";
    return false;
  }
  else if (GThumb2.length > 2) {
    BErr.style.display = "block";
    BErr.innerHTML = "Please make sure the thumbnail file name has no periods(.) within it.";
    return false;
  }
  else if (imgExt.indexOf(GThumb2[1]) == -1) {
    BErr.style.display = "block";
    BErr.innerHTML = "Thumbnail file format is invalid. (Only JPG, JIFF, JPEG, GIF, TIFF are allowed.)";
    return false;

  }
  else if (gameExt.indexOf(GFile2[1]) == -1) {
        BErr.style.display = "block";
        BErr.innerHTML = "Game file format is invalid.";
        return false;
  }
  else {
  var TSize = document.forms.game_sub.game_thumb.form[0].size;
  if (TSize > 1000000) {
    BErr.style.display = "block";
    BErr.innerHTML = "Thumbnail is too big. (Max size: 1MB)";
    return false;
  }
  else {
    BErr.style.display = "block";
    BErr.innerHTML = "Error";
    return false;
  }
  }
}
else {
    BErr.style.display = "block";
    BErr.innerHTML = "Your browser is outdated and cannot support file upload. Please update to latest version.";
    return false;

}
}
```

I tested it on my localhost server and on jsbin.com and it worked. But oddly, as time passed, it somehow just stops working. And this has happened twice. I worked on it last night, then opened it up this morning, same thing happened. I fixed it. Then this afternoon, looked at it again and same thing...

Comment: In the second last else statement, I put the variable for TSize within it so it would be executed last, as prior to putting it at the top with the rest of the variables. It allowed the beginning part to be executed, but once it reaches that else statement, It totally skips the if `(TSize > 1000000)` and goes to the else (Which I  left empty but only added the `BErr.innerHTML = "Error"` after it stopped working to see if it would be executed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code doesn't do anything close to what you think, and there is no jQuery in that code.

The `form` property of an `input` element returns the form that it is in, so `document.forms.game_sub.game_thumb.form` returns the same value as `document.forms.game_sub`.

Using `[0]` on the form gets the first field in the form, which is the name input field, and using `.size` on that reads the attribute `size` from the name input field.

The `size` attribute is used to specify the width of the `input` in characters.

I think that you are looking for the `files` property:

```
var TSize = document.forms.game_sub.game_thumb.files[0].size;
```

Comment: wow. it works thanks. my mistake. I was misleaded b/c for some reason it worked the first time. no idea why.